# Measure time of executing HTTP request stages when it reaches to a server

Tags: node.js, performance, http, request, fastify

I'm creating a *Fastify* app that takes and returns piece of info from *Redis* database. This app executes about **4 ms**. It is time from the moment when the request is coming to the Fastify app, and till the moment when the reply is returning (I've added Fastify hooks `onRequest` and `onResponse` respectivelly to measure it).

From a web browser point of view, the request takes about **188 ms**. I've applied the [superagent-node-http-timings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-node-http-timings) package to measure time for each stage of the request.

The output is like this:

```
{
    "analysisResult": {
        "url": "https://my.website.dev/endpoint",
        "status": 200,
        "timings": {
            "socketAssigned": 0.120599,
            "dnsLookup": 31.804462,
            "tcpConnection": 3.499232,
            "tlsHandshake": 20.878652,
            "firstByte": 131.116467,
            "contentTransfer": 0.854089,
            "total": 188.273501
        }
    }
}
```

How to introspect processes (and times that these processes consume) that are happened in-between `tlsHandshake` and `firstByte` stages?